# WCF Webservice output formatted XML using DataContract

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, wcf, datacontract

I have a requirement to convert a class object in WCF web service to output an `XML` and the format should be something like:

```
<dataset>
    <datasetitem>
        <label>account id</label>
        <value>12345</value>
    </datasetitem>
    <datasetitem>
        <label>address</label>
        <value>123 someting ave.</value>
    </datasetitem>
    <status>true</status>
    <errormessage></errormessage>
</dataset>
```

which was converted from class like:

```
public class dataset
{
   int accountID {get; set;}
   string address {get;set;}
}
```

I did this by creating `XElement` manually, and loop through it.
I wonder is it is possible to do this in `DataContract` or `CollectionDataContract` in any way?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does status and error message stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decorating your class with XmlSerializerFormat? instead of the default DataContractSerializerFormat?

Comment: I have. But I can only change the tag name, not making the variables or properties as label tag.